# Laravel - connection between two tables

Tags: php, laravel

so I'm creating a simple event website where each event has attendees, and each of those attendees is a user, so basically there is the attendee table there is an id (incremental), event_id and user_id.

I currently have an event page where I am able to display the different attendees, but only by their own attributes (id, event_id or user_id). I'd like to find a way to do a query (something like this: `select name from user where id = user_id`) but I have no idea where to do that.

Here is the code I think is necessary to understand the problem, please let me know if there is something else you may need: (im using laravel with Model View Controller organization)~

**web.php**

```
Route::get('event/{id}', 'EventController@show');
```

**Event.php**

```
class Event extends Authenticatable
{
    public function attendees() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Attendee');
    }
}
```

**EventController**

```
class EventController extends Controller
{
    public function show($id)
    {
      $event = DB::table('event')->where('id', $id)->get();
      $event_find = Event::find($id);
      return view('pages.event', ['event' => $event, 'features' => $event_find->features, 'attendees' => $event_find->attendees]);
    }
}
```

**event.blade.php**

```
      </div>
        <div class="event-features">
          <h1 class="list-title">
            Attendee list
          </h1>
          <ul class="attendee-list pdl1em">
            @each('partials.event_attendee_list', $attendees, 'attendee')
          </ul>
      </div>
```

**event_attendee_list.blade.php**

```
<li> {{ $attendee->id }} </li>
```

Once again, if there is any code missing that you need to understand the problem, please let me know :)

Thanks alot for your time

Comment: `$event = DB::table('event')->where('id', $id)->get();` and `$event_find = Event::find($id);` - Why? You're querying the database for the same row _twice_, one as a `Collection` of a single `stdClass` object (silly), one as an `Event` model instance (correct). Just use `$event = Event::find($id);`.

Comment: To answer your actual question, `select name from user where id = user_id` can be done as `$user = User::find($userId)`, then `$user->name`. Please read Laravel's documentation on Models and Relationships; you don't seem to have a grasp on those basic concepts yet: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent and https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: You really should be using [many-to-many relationships here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) where the attendee table is the pivot table between events and users.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show your attendee model, but there should be another relationship in there that links the attendee's to the user. e.g.

```
/**
 * Get the user that belongs to this attendee.
 */
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

This should allow you to access the user's info on the attendee object like so...

```
$attendee->user->name
```

Best practice would be to eager load the relationships to prevent extra DB queries.

```
// Controller
$event = Event::with(['attendees', 'attendees.user'])->find($id);

//View
@foreach($event->attendees as $attendee)
    {{ $attendee->user->name }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: `Event::with(['attendees', 'attendees.user'])` can be rewritten as `Event::with('attendees.user')`; when you do `relationship.nested`, it implicitly loads both relationships; `['relationship.nested']` _is_ `['relationship', 'relationshop.nested']`